# Getting an IllegalArgumentException error on random.nextInt(argument)

Tags: java, android, random, illegalargumentexception

i am getting illegalArgumentException on error line.

```
      private final static int SPOT_DIAMETER=100;
      private int viewWidth;

      .

      .

      .


     @Override
      protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
      viewHeight=h;
      viewWidth=w;

     }
```

"viewWidth-SPOT_DIAMETER" returns integer,isnt it?How i solve this error?

```
    public void addNewSpot(){



   int x=random.nextInt(viewWidth-SPOT_DIAMETER);//error line
   .

   .
   .
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As specified by Random.nextInt(int) [JavaDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextInt(int)), you'll get that exception if you call it with a negative number, which is probably what's happening.

```
Parameters:
n - the bound on the random number to be returned. Must be positive.

Returns:
the next pseudorandom, uniformly distributed int value between 0 (inclusive) and n (exclusive) from this random number generator's sequence

Throws:
IllegalArgumentException - if n is not positive
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you're putting a number, which bigger, than 100 (your `SPOT_DIAMETER`), when you're calling the `onSizeChanged()` method? Check it, because as JSlain already said, this exception throws when randomizer is taking a negative number.

Also, maybe your method doesn't work/called and your `viewWidth` variable is empty, when you're trying to call a randomizer.

Comment: i learned that the variable viewWidth returns always 0 so random.nextInt(0) gives exception  and i'm  searching that why getWidth() returns 0 now ?

Comment: I don't know. How can i understand why `getWidth()` returns 0 if i didn't see your code?) And you have `random.nextInt(-100)`, not just 0 if `viewWidth` contains 0. Try to debug.

Answer (score -1):

Use `viewWidth.SPOT_DIAMETER` assuming it is a public constant.

Comment: I dont understand how to use viewWidth.SPOT_DIAMETER as a public constant i'm new sorry :(

Comment: just change your `-` to `.`